# TypeScript union + generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got some generic type

```
export interface Generic<T>
{
...
}
```

I want to use it as the type for some other generic e.g.

```
let generics: Array<Generic> = [];
```

Obviously that doesn't work as I haven't specified its own type. Is there a way for me to create a union type which encapsulates all possible types for T? (So I can then do `let generics: Array<Union>`)

For example, if my program happens to provide string, number, ClassA and InterfaceB as possibilities for T, this union type would be `string | number | ClassA | InterfaceB`. But I can't know/declare those upfront (which would defeat the purpose of the generic anyway)

I've tried various approaches but the "compiler" is never happy.

Comment: No, this is not possible as stated, assuming that `Generic<T>` depends on `T` in an invariant way (your `...` pseudocode isn't a [mre] so it's hard to say in general) and that your `Union` type doesn't already exist in TypeScript (again, this is not an [mre]). You're looking for so-called *existentially quantified generics* as requested in [ms/TS#14466](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), but those are not directly supported. You can encode them in TypeScript, but it might be more trouble than it's worth. Please [edit] to give a true [me] and someone can give you more advice.